# how do i keep the items in a comboBox from duplicating in javafx?

Tags: java, combobox, javafx

I made a single  editable combo box.....and when you type something in it whatever you type goes to the bottom of the list. The problem i am having is when i click on something that is already in the combo box it doesn't just get selected it also adds again into the combo box as a new entry creating a "Duplicate" any ideas on how i can prevent that? here is what i have.

```
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

public class ComboBoxProblem extends Application {

Scene scene1;

ObservableList<String> randomStrings;





 public void start(Stage primaryStage)throws Exception{
    primaryStage.setTitle("ComboBox Problem!");
    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    primaryStage.sizeToScene();

    GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();

    scene1 = new Scene(gridPane);

    ComboBox<String> box1 = new ComboBox<String>();

    randomStrings = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            "Cool","Dude","BRO!","Weirdo","IDK"

   );   



   box1.setItems(randomStrings);

   box1.setEditable(true);

   box1.setValue(null);
   box1.setOnAction(event -> {
      String value =

       box1.valueProperty().getValue();


       if( value != String.valueOf(randomStrings)){


           randomStrings.addAll(box1.valueProperty().getValue());
           box1.setValue(null);
       }


   });
   gridPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
   gridPane.setConstraints(box1,0,0);



   gridPane.getChildren().addAll(box1);


   primaryStage.setScene(scene1);
   primaryStage.show();

  }




  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);

  }

  }
```

Comment: @ItachiUchiha again thanks for answering yet another one of my noob   questions i really appreciate your help

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please go through the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). For starters, comment on the answers if you want to communicate something. Accept an answer if it helped to solve your problem. If none did and you have re-created a solution which does solve it, you can post it and accept it. Accepting an answer helps future readers facing similar issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another condition on the button's action to check if the string already exists in the list of items. If not, add it.

```
!box1.getItems().contains(value)
```

The condition is to be added to the following statement.

```
if (!value.equals(String.valueOf(randomStrings)) &&
                                  !box1.getItems().contains(value)){
    randomStrings.addAll(value);
    box1.setValue(null);
}
```

As correctly pointed out by @uluk, the way you are comparing Strings is incorrect and you must use `equals` in place of `!=`

Answer (score 0):

Comparing the String values with `!=` or `==` operators is erroneous.

```
value != String.valueOf(randomStrings)  // Incorrect
value.equals(String.valueOf(randomStrings)) // Correct but not logical in your use case
```

You may check the input value then add it to the items of the combobox:

```
box1.setOnAction( event ->
{
    if ( box1.getValue() != null && !box1.getValue().trim().isEmpty() )
    {
        String value = box1.getValue().trim();
        if ( !randomStrings.contains( value ) )
        {
            randomStrings.add( value );
            box1.setValue( null );
        }
    }
} );
```